# PowerShell Update multiple worksheets in a workbook (Excel-file) with separate corresponding csv-files

Tags: excel, powershell

I have an excel file with different worksheets, whose content is regularly updated with a single macro.
The user have to click on each worksheet in turn and execute the macro. The macro asks for a different csv-file for each worksheet, which have to be selected from file Folder manually.

**Here is what the script have to do in background:**

- read the workbook from a csv-file “excelfile1.csv”
- read the worksheets from a csv-file “worksheets.csv” with list of worksheets (company1, company2, company3, etc...)
- activate worksheet named "company1", start macro, macro asks for file named "accounting-company1.csv". Confirm, Wait and Macro then reports that worksheet with the name "Company1" has been updated.
- activate worksheet named "company2", start macro, macro asks for file named "accounting-company2.csv". Confirm, Wait andMacro then reports that worksheet named "Company2" has been updated.
- activate worksheet named "company3", macro start, macro asks for file named "accounting-company3.csv". Confirm, Wait and Macro then reports that worksheet named "Company3" has been updated. Etc....

I am grateful for any support ;-)

Here is my script to be corrected:

```
 # Open Excel file
    $excel = new-object -comobject excel.application
    $filePath = "u:\Test_CompanyAccouting.xlsm"
    $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)
    $excel.Visible = $true
    # Get Names of existing Worksheets

    $worksheets = Get-ChildItem -Path u:\List_WorksheetsNames.csv | ForEach- 
    Object {$_.name}
    forEach ($Worksheet in $Worksheets) {
    $WS = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item($Worksheet)
    $WS.Activate()
    $excel.Run("MacroAccounting")
    }

    $workbook.save()
    $workbook.close()
    $excel.quit()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you clarify what is the problem you have with the current script? What has gone wrong and what is the expected behavior?

Comment: Hello,

sorry for the delay

the problem is that i want to avoid that when the script runs the user manually selects the excel sheet, starts the macro and manually selects the appropriate csv file from the folder.

thanks